# angular 2 issue error TS1068: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected. app/chat.component.ts

Tags: angular

I am getting below issue when i am running npm start

app/chat.component.ts(20,9): error TS1068: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.
app/chat.component.ts(47,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {messageData} from './message';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

@Component({
    selector: 'chat-message',
    templateUrl: './app/middlepanel/chat.component.html',
})

export class chatComponent {
    socket: any;


    this.socket = io('http://localhost:8000');
    console.log(this.socket);

    this.socket.emit('welcome', " demo msg");

    this.socket.on('sample', function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);

    });

    this.socket.emit('joinServer', {
        userName: "punit",
        orgId: "786",
        deviceToken: "11111",
        osType: "window"
    });

    this.socket.on('update-people', function(msg) {
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(msg));
        console.log(msg);  
    });  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the assignments in a constructor or a life-cycle hook:

```
...
export class chatComponent {
    socket: any;

    constructor(){
     this.socket = io('http://localhost:8000');
     console.log(this.socket);

     this.socket.emit('welcome', " demo msg");

     this.socket.on('sample', function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
     });

     this.socket.emit('joinServer', {
        userName: "punit",
        orgId: "786",
        deviceToken: "11111",
        osType: "window"
     });

     this.socket.on('update-people', function(msg) {
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(msg));
        console.log(msg);  
     });  
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback i am implementing angular 2.0 with socket.io chat app .I need your suggestion should i import these  two module ,some demo app i have seen they were using this module for socket client 
 import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

Comment: @punit ehm it's a bit unclear for me to answer a question like that from here. Need to see the use case etc. You should ask another question about it with the use case and code.

Comment: when i am putting  'joinServer'  emit function out side of constructor function it throwing again error "Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected".we can not put all sockets "emit" and "on" function in constructor function because some emit i need to call on event based like when i click on button then message in text field  will emit to server .so what approach i should use for this.  that is why i ask that Observable will help or i can implement without it.

Comment: @punit What I understand from that comment is that you are again doing an assignment operation outside of the constructor and it is of course not working. I understand nothing more unfortunately. Ask another question which describes the issue with a minimal example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask