# A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected. src/app/app.component.ts(129,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected

Tags: javascript, angular6, angular7

i'm getting this error
 error TS1068: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.
src/app/app.component.ts(129,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
in angular 6

```
const dataList = Object.keys(this.data).map(key => this.data[key]);
  let contents = this.dataList.map(d => Object.keys(d).map(key => d[key]))

  if(contents && contents.length) {
  var firstData = contents[0];

  firstData.forEach((content,ind) => {
  contents.forEach((content,index) => this.resultData[index] = content[ind]);
  this.resultList.push(this.resultData)
  })    
  }
```

how to declare a variable in angular 6

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: let contents = this.dataList.map(d => Object.keys(d).map(key => d[key]))

in this  line (let content)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this line

```
let contents = this.dataList.map(d => Object.keys(d).map(key => d[key]))
```

Change it to

```
let contents = dataList.map(d => Object.keys(d).map(key => d[key]));
```

As `datalist` is not a property of class, you don't need to use `this`

Comment: by removing this it is shoing this error

Cannot find name 'dataList'.

Answer (score 0):

In the first line you are defining dataList as const, and in the next line you're using this.dataList. May be the problem is this.dataList is not defined.

Comment: having problem in both lines 

const dataList = Object.keys(this.data).map(key => this.data[key]);
  let contents = this.dataList.map(d => Object.keys(d).map(key => d[key]))

how to declare a variable

Comment: Are you sure this code inside the constructor function? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41929758/5659132 Please have a look at this answer. May be you are facing the same issue.